# how I can minimize my app, open safari mobile and reopen my app on the very last point I used it

Tags: java, ios, appium

I am working with a hybrid app and when I register a new user for the app, I press a button on the native view and a new screen is open and it is redirected to a webpage, I complete the user section press a button and a verification code is sent to my email, how can I minimize my app and open the safari to navigate to my email??? I have the webview, send keys to email field, click on button to send the code and driver.get(URL); but if close the mailbox after getting the code and try to open my app again, it's open from the very first screen and if I continue I'll send another code

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between Apps is pretty easy:

```
HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("bundleId", "com.apple.safari");
driver.executeScript("mobile: launchApp", args);
//Navigate to your email, etc.

// re-activate your native app and use it
args.put("bundleId", yourAppBundleId);
driver.executeScript("mobile: activateApp", args);
```

But I suggest you to replace direct email navigation via UI with API calls for reliablity & speed: you can check mail via API and confirm registration via your App APIs.